# Connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-premise web service with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, dynamics-crm

Are there any online resources which show the basic steps to access the Microsoft CRM on-premise web service with a client written in Java?

Which web service toolkit should I use?

I tried it with JAXB but there is a conflict in the WSDL element naming which requires a class customization. If I find the correct binding fix, I will post it here.

Comment: have you implemented Ms dynamics CRM, if so let you guide me to achieve the same. looking for you response.

Comment: @SenthilMg no we used a WCF client and a simple file based message interchange. See below for a hint that Axis 2 can be used.

Comment: i'm facing a problem  Need help to fix the error, org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:296) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:190) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommo‌​ns(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTra‌​nsportSender.java:208)..

Comment: @SenthilMg this should be a new question. It looks like the user credentials are wrong. Try to pass the same user name and passwort which you use in a browser to access the WSDL. The code shown in the answer below uses NTLM authentication, is this the same auth method in your environment?

Comment: below answer am getting error above at     RetrieveMultipleResponseDocument rmrd = stub.RetrieveMultiple(rmd,  catd, null, null); any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Microsoft Dynamics CRM application on premise version uses Active Directory authentication.
Although I never tried referencing the Microsoft Dynamics CRM web services from Java, I am sure it is feasible, as these are standard web services and therefor can be referenced from Java via SOAP, just like any other web service.

```
public class TestCRM {  

private static String endpointURL = "http://server:port/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";  
private static String userName = "username";  
private static String password = "password";  
private static String host = "server";  
private static int portport = port;  

//To make sure you are using the correct domain open ie and try to reach the service. The same domain you entered there is needed here  
private static String domain = "DOMAIN";   

private static String orgName = "THIS_IS_REQUIRED"; //this does the work....  


public static void main(String[] args) {  

    CrmServiceStub stub;  
    try {  
        stub = new CrmServiceStub(endpointURL);  
        setOptions(stub._getServiceClient().getOptions());  

        RetrieveMultipleDocument rmd = RetrieveMultipleDocument.Factory.newInstance();  
        RetrieveMultiple rm = RetrieveMultiple.Factory.newInstance();  

        QueryExpression query = QueryExpression.Factory.newInstance();  
        query.setColumnSet(AllColumns.Factory.newInstance());  
        query.setEntityName(EntityName.######.toString());  
        //query.setFilter...  

        rm.setQuery(query);  
        rmd.setRetrieveMultiple(rm);  

        //Now this is required. Without it all i got was 401s errors  
        CrmAuthenticationTokenDocument catd = CrmAuthenticationTokenDocument.Factory.newInstance();  
        CrmAuthenticationToken token = CrmAuthenticationToken.Factory.newInstance();  
        token.setAuthenticationType(0);     
        token.setOrganizationName(orgName);  
        catd.setCrmAuthenticationToken(token);  

        boolean fetchNext = true;  
        while(fetchNext){  
            RetrieveMultipleResponseDocument rmrd = stub.RetrieveMultiple(rmd,  catd, null, null);  
            RetrieveMultipleResponse rmr = rmrd.getRetrieveMultipleResponse();  
            BusinessEntityCollection bec = rmr.getRetrieveMultipleResult();  

            String pagingCookie = bec.getPagingCookie();  
            fetchNext = bec.getMoreRecords();  

            ArrayOfBusinessEntity aobe = bec.getBusinessEntities();  
            BusinessEntity[] myEntitiesAtLast = aobe.getBusinessEntityArray();  

            for(int i=0; i<myEntitiesAtLast.length; i++){  
                //cast to whatever you asked for...  
                ### myEntity = (###) myEntitiesAtLast[i];  
            }  
        }  
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}  

private static void setOptions(Options options){  
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();  

    List authSchemes = new ArrayList();  
    authSchemes.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);   
    auth.setAuthSchemes(authSchemes);   

    auth.setUsername(userName);  
    auth.setPassword(password);  
    auth.setHost(host);  
    auth.setPort(port);  
    auth.setDomain(domain);  
    auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(false); //it doesnt matter...  
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);  
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, "true"); //i think this is good.. not required though  
}
```

Comment: This source code looks good, almost exactly like the C# example code (which I used successfully). Do you know which SOAP toolkit has generated the service stub classes in Java?

Comment: @Joe, I tried out your snippet provided here but it results unsuccess, can you please provide your valuable suggestion to implement CRM.Showing error at RetrieveMultipleDocument rmd = RetrieveMultipleDocument.Factory.newInstance();

Comment: xception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.microsoft.schemas.crm._2007.webservices.ExecuteDocument$Execute$Factory.newInstance(ExecuteDocument.java:70)
 at javaMSCRM.Login.main(Login.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.s0C7B6541D611A1749D5105A4C55EC974.TypeSystemHolder.

Comment: @joe, Need help to fix the error, org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:296)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:190)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:364)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:208)

Comment: @joe - What would the code look like for connecting to crm 2011? Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Java -> SOAP -> MS CRM 2011 Online : http://zsvoboda.blogspot.com/2011/03/connecting-to-microsoft-crm-2011-online.html

Answer (score 1):

The stub has been created with the Apache Axis2 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can find resources here. You can even work with an example is available in Dynamics CRM SDK. As Manuel Freiholz said, you have to use Axis2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamics-coe/archive/2013/09/21/integrating-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-with-java-and-other-non-net-clients.aspx

Alternatively, you can use RESTFul web services through the OData interface offered by Dynamics (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334279.aspx)